# Error migrating from Wildfly 21 to Wildfly 27 with Hibernate 6.3.0

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, wildfly

I'm in the process of migrating a system from Wildfly 21 to Wildfly 27. In the previous system, we were using hibernate-core 5, but for Wildfly 27, we've upgraded to version 6.3.0.

I managed to address all the issues related to migrating to jakarta.persistence, but now I'm facing a specific problem that I can't resolve. Below are the error details:

```
10:50:21,061 DEBUG [org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Implicitly destroying ServiceRegistry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
10:50:21,062 INFO  [org.hibernate.orm.beans] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH10005004: Stopping BeanContainer : org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl@6c72da89
10:50:21,063 INFO  [org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000369: Error stopping service [class org.hibernate.resource.beans.internal.ManagedBeanRegistryImpl]: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.spi.ContainedBeanImplementor.release()" because "this.delegateContainedBean" is null
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.internal.CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl$BeanImpl.release(CdiBeanContainerExtendedAccessImpl.java:132)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.spi.AbstractCdiBeanContainer.forEachBean(AbstractCdiBeanContainer.java:138)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.resource.beans.container.spi.AbstractCdiBeanContainer.stop(AbstractCdiBeanContainer.java:144)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.resource.beans.internal.ManagedBeanRegistryImpl.stop(ManagedBeanRegistryImpl.java:134)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.stopService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:374)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:357)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:131)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.deRegisterChild(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:407)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.destroy(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:364)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceRegistryImplementor.close(ServiceRegistryImplementor.java:30)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:402)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425)
    at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate6@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:45)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:171)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:214)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

10:50:21,063 DEBUG [org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v60.InfinispanRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Stop region factory
10:50:21,063 DEBUG [org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v60.InfinispanRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Clear region references
10:50:21,063 DEBUG [org.infinispan.hibernate.cache.v60.InfinispanRegionFactory] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Stop cache manager
10:50:21,066 DEBUG [org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.BootstrapServiceRegistryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Implicitly destroying Boot-strap registry on de-registration of all child ServiceRegistries
10:50:21,066 DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) HHH000031: Closing
10:50:21,066 DEBUG [org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) Eating error closing SF on failed attempt to start it
10:50:21,066 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 80) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.persistenceunit."sigeprs-3.0.21-SNAPSHOT.war#SIGEP_PU": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.persistenceunit."sigeprs-3.0.21-SNAPSHOT.war#SIGEP_PU": jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SIGEP_PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:199)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:129)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at org.wildfly.security.elytron-base@2.0.0.Final//org.wildfly.security.manager.WildFlySecurityManager.doChecked(WildFlySecurityManager.java:664)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:214)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1990)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)
Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SIGEP_PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1509)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1430)
    at org.hibernate.jipijapa-hibernate6@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate.TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.build(TwoPhaseBootstrapImpl.java:45)
    at org.jboss.as.jpa@27.0.1.Final//org.jboss.as.jpa.service.PersistenceUnitServiceImpl$1$1.run(PersistenceUnitServiceImpl.java:171)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: Only support for basic-valued, entity-valued and embedded model-parts have been implemented : tipo [null]
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor$AttributeFetchDescriptor.getFetchMemento(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:439)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor$AttributeFetchDescriptor.resolve(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:421)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor$EntityResultDescriptor.lambda$resolve$0(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:285)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap.forEach(HashMap.java:1421)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor$EntityResultDescriptor.resolve(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:282)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.lambda$resolve$0(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:131)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.query.SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.resolve(SqlResultSetMappingDescriptor.java:130)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.lambda$prepare$3(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:193)
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$Values.forEach(HashMap.java:1065)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataImpl.visitNamedResultSetMappingDefinition(MetadataImpl.java:261)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.prepare(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:191)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.query.spi.QueryEngine.prepare(QueryEngine.java:380)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:415)
    at org.hibernate@6.1.5.Final//org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1425)
    ... 12 more

10:50:21,069 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "sigeprs-3.0.21-SNAPSHOT.war")]) - failure description: {"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.persistenceunit.\"sigeprs-3.0.21-SNAPSHOT.war#SIGEP_PU\"" => "jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SIGEP_PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: SIGEP_PU] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
    Caused by: org.hibernate.NotYetImplementedFor6Exception: Only support for basic-valued, entity-valued and embedded model-parts have been implemented : tipo [null]"}}
```

Before posting here, I tried the following solutions:

- Checked all dependencies to ensure there are no conflicts.
- Researched the NotYetImplementedFor6Exception error to better understand the issue.
- Reviewed the persistence.xml configuration to ensure
  everything is correct.

However, I'm still stuck with this error. Has anyone encountered this or have any suggestions on how to resolve it?

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: It seems that there is something around the 'tipo' attribute that causes this.

Comment: You are saying you use 6.3.0, but stacktrace says 6.1.5 is used. Aren't you relying on feature from 6.3.0, which is not implemented in 6.1.5 yet?

Comment: Hibernate 6.1.5 is a "feature pack" with Wildfly 27